# How to get data from yml file in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create the file called setting.yml and it will have data like

```
Route1: users
Route2 : profile
```

So that in my controller i can get the route1 from that Yml file

File is in `/app/config/settings.yml` and not included in config.yml

Comment: where is your file? and did you include it in the main config.yml?

Comment: No its not in main config file but separate in `config/settings.yml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things:

If your configuration is simple, add the values you need under a "parameters" entry, either in your main config.yml file or in a file which you import from your main config.file. For example:

```
parameters:
    Route1: users
    Route2 : profile
```

Then in your controller, use this code to get one of the parameters:

```
$route = $this->container->getParameter('Route1');
```

Or, if you want a really flexible configuration, you can implement a semantic configuration for your bundle. See this link for all the information you will need:

http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/extension.html

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import it in your config file for it to work

**config.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: settings.yml }
```

But I am not sure you are using routing correctly

See the documentation for how to use [Routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) properly

Comment: No no , dont confuse with main symfony routing. I have made ,my own own login listener and depending upon the user role i am routing to different URL. i just want to put routes based on roles in yml file so that they can be chnaged. But how can i get the route1 variable inside symfony